# Создание второго лога используя Nlog

Tags: c#, логирование

Задача: создать два лога.Первый для записи Info, второй для записи Errors. Использую NLog. С первой половиной задачи справился: создал первый логгер и записал его в файл (file.txt). Не получается создать второй, прошу помощи.

**Файл App.config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
      <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="D://file.txt" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
</configuration>
```

**Фрагмент кода с логгером:**

```
 public partial class FormDepocs : Form
    {
        Depo depo;
        FormSelectLoco form;
        private Logger log;

        public FormDepocs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
            depo = new Depo(5);
            for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            {
                listBoxLevels.Items.Add("Уровень " + i);
            }
            listBoxLevels.SelectedIndex = depo.getCurrentLevel;
            Draw();
        }
```

Далее строчкой  `log.Info("Сообщение с логом!");` добавляю все в лог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В настройках есть так называемые цели (target) и правила (rules).

Посмотрим ваш код:

```
<targets>
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="D://file.txt" />
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logfile" />
</rules>
```

Вы имеете:

- Одну цель (записать в файл `D://file.txt"`).
- Одно правило (отлавливать любые логи, минимальный уровень которых `Info` и отдавать их цели `logfile`).

То есть тут все довольно просто, действуйте аналогично...

К примеру, хотите записать в отельный файл только ошибки:

- Создаете новую цель

  ```
  <target name="errorfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="D://errors.txt" />
  ```
- Создаем новое правило, которое будет отлавливать ошибки `Warn`, `Error` и `Fatal`. (заметьте, я тут явно указал какие уровни логов мне нужны, можно и указать минимальный).

  ```
  <logger name="*" levels="Fatal,Error" writeTo="errorfile" />
  ```

Все, остальное за вас сделает сам `NLog`. Советую прочитать [документацию](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial#multiple-targets).

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! Все получилось.